# Debug TS Files on Angular 12 Chrome Debug

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, debugging

i've just update my angular project from 9 to 12 version.
Before i was able to debug the ts files with the chrome inspector but now i can't see them anymore.
Can someone help me?

this is my tsconfig.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQSRy.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue after updating a project from version 11 to version 13. I simply am unable to do any debugging in chrome: i cannot use ctrl+p to open a file, and "debugger;" statements are not catched.